# how to justify column after add/delete column in el-table of element ui Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, rendering, element-ui

I need to create a table/datagrid using Element UI where user can select the column to be displayed. I have created it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/hh4zx15w/3/)

I want the user to be able to change the width of the columns, which is possible  using `border` property.
My problem is that when user removes the column for which the width was set by dragging the border - the width remains as it was for that column.
I want the columns to justify equally after column changes, sort of like re-render them.

Answer (score 1):

Ahh ! I just had to bind key to it. Read full doc [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key)